# how to check for an empty selection [] using jquery?

Tags: jquery, events, jquery-mobile, event-handling, click

I'm using this from Jquery Mobile to check whether an element clicked was a link:

```
 function findClosestLink(ele) {    
        var self = this;
        while (ele){
            if (ele.nodeName.toLowerCase() == "a"){
                break;
                }
            ele = ele.parentNode;
            }
        return ele;
        }
```

It's being called like this:

```
$(document).addEventListener( "click", function( e  ){
        var link = $( findClosestLink(e.target) );
        console.log(link);
        // routine
   });
```

**Queston:**
When clicking on screen, the function returns an empty array **[]**. I'm trying to check for this using

```
    if (!link) {
       return;
    }
```

But this doesn't work. How do I check for []?

Thanks for help!

Comment: Cool. Works! Can you make it answer? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
if (link.length == 0) { 
     return;
}
```

If no link is found, then length will be 0.

Answer (score 2):

The return items is an `array` so, you have to use `.length` property to check.

```
if (!link.length) {
    // your stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do this instead, its cleaner and easier to read and understand :

```
$(document).click(function(e) {
  var $target = $(e.target);
  if($target.is("a")) {
     console.log('link');
  } else {
     // not a link
  }
});
```

This uses [.click()](http://api.jquery.com/click/) and [event.target](http://api.jquery.com/event.target/)

Comment: Would be easier, but Jquery Mobile burries a lot of elements inside links, so I need to traverse up from the clicked element, which in Jquery Mobile usually is a span.ui-text inside span.ui-btn-inner inside a.ui-btn.

Comment: in jQuery 1.7+ you can do:  `$(document).on('click', 'a', function(){ .... });` and it will only capture clicks on "a" tags.